# Generate time-domain random signal from PSD

Tags: discrete-signals, power-spectral-density, random, stochastic

Given an analytical description of the PSD, for example (MATLAB "pseudocode"):

```
N = 20400;
bw = 2 * 2040 / N; % double-sided spectrum, 20% occupied
PSD = zeros(N,1);
P0 = sigma * sqrt(N/bw); % sigma^2 = (P0^2/N) * bw
PSD(1:2040) = P0;
PSD(18362:end) = P0;
```

what is the "correct" way to generate a time-domain signal $x[n]$ which is a realization of this PSD, i.e. which has variance of $\sigma^2$ and a DFT where all bins $2041, \dots, 18361$ are zero?

I found this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/264846. However, I am confused since there only the phase is taken randomly but not the magnitude which would result in a perfect "brick-wall" spectrum when taking the DFT of each realization (because the magnitude and magnitude-squared is not random). However, this is only the case if the number of samples approaches infinity.

Important: I do **not** want to generate iid. white Gaussian samples and filter them - I would like to generate the random signal in DFT domain and then use the inverse DFT to generate the time domain signal.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to filter white noise to shape its PSD the way you want it? That's the only way to go.

Comment: Loos like you have a PSD for band-stop filter. As Matt L said you can try i.i.d. filtering approach to find the time domain process. Take the IDFT of PSD to get sample auto-correlation function. Plug that in to a Yule-walker equation for AR or ARMA to generate realization of random sequence you want.

Comment: I don't think time domain/filtering is the "only way to go" (this is how I do it currently). I want to generate my signal in freuency domain to do some cross checks. The PSD should be something similar to a pdf and I should be able to sample from it, right? But how to get the correct propeties (time domain variance, correlation)? As mentioned, just taking the phase randomly (and the magnitude equal to the PSD) as described in the link is wrong.

Comment: The PSD is definitely not similar to a PDF. What do you mean?

Comment: The power spectral density tells you **nothing** about the _distribution_ of the random variables that you wish to generate; except indirectly it says that the random variables must have specific correlations as described by the inverse Fourier transform (autocorrelation function) of the power spectral density.  For example, a sequence of iid _Laplacian_ random variables (pdf $\frac 12 e^{-|x|}$) will have the same flat PSD as a sequence of iid zero-mean Gaussian variables with the same variance. Similarly if the target PSD is not flat; though it is more difficult to generate ......

Comment: (continued).... correlated Laplacian random variables than correlated Gaussian random variables.  However, generating iid random variables and then _filtering_ to get the desired PSD will always work though it won't give nice distributions for the filter output. But no matter, the mills of MATLAB will grind it out for you.

Comment: Alright, it's not a pdf. However, for my PSD, it still tells me that there is zero probability of signal energy between bins 2041 and 18361 and non-zero probability otherwise. The question is the same and clear: _How to generate a random signal (Gaussian distribution) in frequency domain based on PSD?_ I agree that _in practice_ you would filter in time domain but this is not my question. Is the information in the link correct or not (as I assume)? If it is not possible indeed, why?

Comment: One more: I also found the same approach from the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787040/synthesize-psd-in-matlab. Again, the magnitude of a realization is constant which sounds wrong to me (because only the phases are random). If I create a signal in time domain using `randn`, filter it (e.g. brick wall) and taking the DFT, the amplitudes are certainly not constant (they are only if averaging them over $N\rightarrow \infty$ realization)

Comment: @divB just want to confirm your suspicion about using constant magnitudes in the frequency domain; it's *wrong* and a very common mistake.