# Can realizations of a filtered Gaussian white noise process be represented as a Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, noise

Suppose we have a noise process $V(t)$ which is the result of passing Gaussian white noise through a filter with frequency response function $H(\omega)$.
Can we represent realizations of this process as a Fourier transform
$$V(t) = \int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} M(\omega) e^{i \phi(\omega)}$$
where $M(\omega)$ and $\phi(\omega)$ are random variables?
If so, what are the statistics of $M(\omega)$ and $\phi(\omega)$?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it makes sense to talk about the Fourier transform of a (realization of a) random process, because it generally doesn't exist if no further restrictions are imposed. This problem is also discussed [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=QkLy3mvvw1cC&lpg=PA448&ots=VX3D2LSbDl&dq=fourier%20transform%20of%20realization%20of%20random%20process&pg=PA448#v=onepage&q&f=false).

What *can* be done is analyze the statistics of the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) and the discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) of a windowed version of a discrete-time stationary random process. This has been done in [this paper](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mrichard/DFT%20of%20Noise.pdf).

Comment: Indeed, the discrete case can be understood using elementary rules of statistics. Could you elaborate on your statement that the FT doesn't exist unless further restrictions are imposed?

Comment: @DanielSank: What I meant is that for the realization of a random process, especially if it's white, i.e. it has infinite power, there is no reason to believe that the conditions for the existence of the Fourier transform are met. In general they aren't (e.g. the function is not $L_1$, etc.).

Comment: Of course. Would this question make more sense if we ask about filtered white noise? I changed the question to ask about filtered white noise. I realize this "pulls the carpet" out from under your answer but I think, given your comments, that the filtered case is the only one worth discussing.

Comment: @DanielSank: I think that even in that case my original answer still holds, because also realizations of a filtered white noise process will generally not be $L_1$ or $L_2$, so their Fourier transform will not exist. I added a link to my answer where this problem is discussed.

Comment: Awesome. I actually discovered the construction shown in that book myself when trying to understand this issue. I suppose as you say it doesn't make sense to define a Fourier transform for a noise process. This leaves a funny feeling though, because I thought I'd heard that it's possible to think of white noise as a Fourier integral where the phases $\phi(\omega)$ are all independent and uniformly distributed.

Comment: @DanielSank: I kind of understand where this comes from, but I don't think it is really correct in any sense, it may just help intuition. This is also related to the way some people try to generate a time domain realization of a random process given a power spectral density ([link](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22587/generate-time-domain-random-signal-from-psd)). But I think that's a waste of time.

Comment: Indeed, constructing realizations of a noise process in the way described in your link does suggest that some sort of Fourier integral representation should be possible. Note, by the way, that people almost always get those numerical constructions of noise wrong because they forget that the amplitudes (not just the phases) of each frequency component are randomly distributed, even for a fixed average power spectral density. I'm inclined to accept this answer but I'll wait a bit to see if someone else has more input.